# Install problem with SOAPUI 5.5.0 on MacOS 10.15.1 (Catalina)

Tags: java, macos, soapui, macos-catalina

I'm not able to install to succesfully install `SoapGUI 5.5.0` on `MacOS 10.15.1` (Catalina) (Java SE6 installed)

After clicking on the `SoapUI 5.5.0 Installer` a error file created on the desktop with the following content:

```
    Exception:

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.SystemFormScreen
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper.invokeOnEDT(GUIHelper.java:737)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.config.AbstractBeanConfig.finishBatch(AbstractBeanConfig.java:51)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.registerScreens(ContextImpl.java:695)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.start(Controller.java:83)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.runInProcess(Installer.java:58)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Installer.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:85)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.MacLauncher.main(MacLauncher.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.SystemFormScreen
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
    at com.sun.beans.finder.MethodFinder$1.create(MethodFinder.java:54)
    at com.sun.beans.finder.MethodFinder$1.create(MethodFinder.java:49)
    at com.sun.beans.util.Cache.get(Cache.java:126)
    at com.sun.beans.finder.MethodFinder.findMethod(MethodFinder.java:81)
    at java.beans.Statement.getMethod(Statement.java:357)
    at java.beans.Statement.invokeInternal(Statement.java:261)
    at java.beans.Statement.access$000(Statement.java:58)
    at java.beans.Statement$2.run(Statement.java:185)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.beans.Statement.invoke(Statement.java:182)
    at java.beans.Expression.getValue(Expression.java:155)
    at com.sun.beans.decoder.ObjectElementHandler.getValueObject(ObjectElementHandler.java:166)
    at com.sun.beans.decoder.NewElementHandler.getValueObject(NewElementHandler.java:123)
    at com.sun.beans.decoder.ElementHandler.endElement(ElementHandler.java:169)
    at com.sun.beans.decoder.DocumentHandler.endElement(DocumentHandler.java:318)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:183)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at com.sun.beans.decoder.DocumentHandler$1.run(DocumentHandler.java:375)
    at com.sun.beans.decoder.DocumentHandler$1.run(DocumentHandler.java:372)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at com.sun.beans.decoder.DocumentHandler.parse(DocumentHandler.java:372)
    at java.beans.XMLDecoder$1.run(XMLDecoder.java:201)
    at java.beans.XMLDecoder$1.run(XMLDecoder.java:199)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.beans.XMLDecoder.parsingComplete(XMLDecoder.java:199)
    at java.beans.XMLDecoder.readObject(XMLDecoder.java:250)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.config.AbstractBeanConfig$2.call(AbstractBeanConfig.java:54)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.config.AbstractBeanConfig$2.call(AbstractBeanConfig.java:51)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper$4.run(GUIHelper.java:727)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

System properties:

java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
exe4j.moduleName=/Volumes/SoapUI/SoapUI 5.5.0 Installer.app
sun.boot.library.path=/private/var/folders/7g/9r0n2jf9743fn5z2_ynd6tfh0000gn/T/E2150FB9-3F02-4D9D-B157-9E21668B04D7-4218-0000020CF462C7B6/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib
java.vm.version=25.181-b13
i4j.jreBundle=/var/folders/7g/9r0n2jf9743fn5z2_ynd6tfh0000gn/T/E2150FB9-3F02-4D9D-B157-9E21668B04D7-4218-0000020CF462C7B6/jre.bundle
gopherProxySet=false
java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/
path.separator=:
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
user.country=NL
sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD
sun.os.patch.level=unknown
install4j.exeDir=/Volumes/SoapUI/
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
user.dir=/Volumes/SoapUI/SoapUI 5.5.0 Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app
java.runtime.version=1.8.0_181-b13
i4j.ownBundlePath=/Volumes/SoapUI/SoapUI 5.5.0 Installer.app
java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.CGraphicsEnvironment
java.endorsed.dirs=/private/var/folders/7g/9r0n2jf9743fn5z2_ynd6tfh0000gn/T/E2150FB9-3F02-4D9D-B157-9E21668B04D7-4218-0000020CF462C7B6/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/endorsed
os.arch=x86_64
java.io.tmpdir=/var/folders/7g/9r0n2jf9743fn5z2_ynd6tfh0000gn/T/
line.separator=

java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
os.name=Mac OS X
sun.java2d.noddraw=true
sun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8
javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
java.library.path=/Users/myhomedirectory/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
sun.awt.enableExtraMouseButtons=true
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.class.version=52.0
sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
os.version=10.15.1
user.home=/Users/myhomedirectory
user.timezone=Europe/Amsterdam
java.awt.printerjob=sun.lwawt.macosx.CPrinterJob
file.encoding=UTF-8
java.specification.version=1.8
java.class.path=/Volumes/SoapUI/SoapUI 5.5.0 Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/i4jruntime.jar
user.name=myhomedirectory
java.vm.specification.version=1.8
sun.java.command=com.install4j.runtime.launcher.MacLauncher
java.home=/private/var/folders/7g/9r0n2jf9743fn5z2_ynd6tfh0000gn/T/E2150FB9-3F02-4D9D-B157-9E21668B04D7-4218-0000020CF462C7B6/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre
sun.arch.data.model=64
user.language=en
java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
awt.toolkit=sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit
java.vm.info=mixed mode
java.version=1.8.0_181
java.ext.dirs=/Users/myhomedirectory/Library/Java/Extensions:/private/var/folders/7g/9r0n2jf9743fn5z2_ynd6tfh0000gn/T/E2150FB9-3F02-4D9D-B157-9E21668B04D7-4218-0000020CF462C7B6/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
sun.boot.class.path=/private/var/folders/7g/9r0n2jf9743fn5z2_ynd6tfh0000gn/T/E2150FB9-3F02-4D9D-B157-9E21668B04D7-4218-0000020CF462C7B6/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/private/var/folders/7g/9r0n2jf9743fn5z2_ynd6tfh0000gn/T/E2150FB9-3F02-4D9D-B157-9E21668B04D7-4218-0000020CF462C7B6/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/private/var/folders/7g/9r0n2jf9743fn5z2_ynd6tfh0000gn/T/E2150FB9-3F02-4D9D-B157-9E21668B04D7-4218-0000020CF462C7B6/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/private/var/folders/7g/9r0n2jf9743fn5z2_ynd6tfh0000gn/T/E2150FB9-3F02-4D9D-B157-9E21668B04D7-4218-0000020CF462C7B6/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/private/var/folders/7g/9r0n2jf9743fn5z2_ynd6tfh0000gn/T/E2150FB9-3F02-4D9D-B157-9E21668B04D7-4218-0000020CF462C7B6/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/private/var/folders/7g/9r0n2jf9743fn5z2_ynd6tfh0000gn/T/E2150FB9-3F02-4D9D-B157-9E21668B04D7-4218-0000020CF462C7B6/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/private/var/folders/7g/9r0n2jf9743fn5z2_ynd6tfh0000gn/T/E2150FB9-3F02-4D9D-B157-9E21668B04D7-4218-0000020CF462C7B6/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/private/var/folders/7g/9r0n2jf9743fn5z2_ynd6tfh0000gn/T/E2150FB9-3F02-4D9D-B157-9E21668B04D7-4218-0000020CF462C7B6/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/classes
install4j.appDir=/Volumes/SoapUI/SoapUI 5.5.0 Installer.app/Contents/Resources/
i4j.tarFile=/Volumes/SoapUI/SoapUI 5.5.0 Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/jre.tar.gz
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
file.separator=/
java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
sun.font.fontmanager=sun.font.CFontManager
sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeBig
sun.cpu.endian=little
install4j.systemLanguage=en
sun.cpu.isalist=
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

I also tried copying a already installed version of SOAPUI 5.5.0 (in the /Applications folder) from another macbook that was upgraded, but i've still couldn't start it. *(<- i know it's dirty, but the other macbook was upgraded to MacOS Catalina and here SOAPUI 5.5.0 was working, mine was a clean install)*

Comment: This was actually the issue:
https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/5620

Answer (score 0):

There are probably an issues with the Catalina Gatekeeper resp. System Integrity Protection. I got it version 5.5.0 installed from the *.dmg file logged in as an administrator